# Can I send a java annotation at he method level, in a MVC controller method, the http request as a parameter?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a standard Spring MVC web application,  and I want to add a custom annotation that takes a parameter and the HttpRequest.

Now I know that annotation parameters are resolved at compile time,  but how does Spring security get access to the session and user and stuff with @PreAuth and stuff...

I am specifically looking to get the HttpRequest.

Ideas how to work around this?

Comment: You're looking for `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, but you might want to mention what exactly you're wanting to do in case there's already an implementation available.

Comment: Looking for the HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

U should implement `PermissionEvaluator`.

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {


public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object target,
        Object permission) {

        return // you logic;
}


public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId,String targetType, Object permission) {
        return // you logic;

}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = 
      new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
    return expressionHandler;
}



@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#foo, 'YOU_CUSTOM_PARAM')")
@PostMapping(value = "/pay")
public Foo create(Foo foo) {
    return foo;
}
```